# Is it possible to install onenote on mountian lion

Tags: macos, onenote

I really want onenote on my mac, but currently I only have mountain lion, which is excluded from installing onenote from Mac app store.

I heard upgrading to Yosemite could be risky, I've a whole macports to worry about.

So is it possible to trick the mac system by changing the version number (I assume this is not that risky and done by easily modifying some registry?), and then get onenote installed?

Also if there's any alternative to onenote, could be also helpful, although onenote is definitely great.

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to run fine on yosemite. I just personally tested it. You can download it here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-onenote/id784801555?mt=12

If you have any questions I'll test anything else for you.

Comment: Thanks for offering to help, but I plan not to upgrade yeosemite that quick, my mountain lion works fine now, plus I've an old macbook.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken Yosemite's replacement will soon be announced at the WWDC, so it might be better to upgrade sooner then later. Also if your mac is getting a little slow you might want to look into an SSD, the price is rapidly dropping and once you experience those speeds you'll never go back

Comment: But I did get the first step done. I tricked the system to think itself to be Yosemite (10.10) by using 'sudo nano -w /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist', so now onenote could be downloaded to /Application, but still not running.

Comment: If it is not allowing you to install it probably requires something that came around in mavericks. have you at least looked into upgrading to Mavericks?

Answer (score 0):

Hacking the OS X version (or the minimum version OneNote requires) isn't a good idea. All of Microsoft's new Office apps, OneNote included, take advantage of Yosemite APIs and frameworks. Even if you could get it installed, it won't open / run property.

Consider upgrading your OS. If it runs slow, one of the best upgrades for a computer is a new SSD. It's amazing the difference it makes.